# How to calculate difference between amount of rows for most recent date and second most recent date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, series

I have the following df:

```
Index     Address     Date     
0  0x06b  2021-12-02  16:03:09.332
1  0x04t  2021-12-03  16:03:09.332
2  0x12c  2021-12-03  16:03:09.332
3  0x3d5  2021-12-04  16:03:09.332
4  0x077  2021-12-04  16:03:09.332
5  0x998  2021-12-04  16:03:09.332
```

I want to calculate the difference in amount of rows (`len()` of the column) between the most recent date (`t`), which in this case is `2021-12-04  16:03:09.332`)and the previous date (`t-1`) but also for any previous date (`t-2, t-3, ..., t-n`).

In this case, the answer for t - (t-1) should be 1, because the most recent date has 3 rows and the secod most recent date has 2 rows. 3-2 = 1.

I have tried implementing the solution in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52459147/find-second-most-recent-date-in-pandas-data-frame), but it does not seem to work.

Comment: len() just tells you the number of characters in the string, and they will be the same each time from what you show. Try taking the difference ie C3-c2 and formatting as hours and minutes.

Comment: You are right, I was not very precise when I mentioned `len()`. what I meant was the length of the column (i.e. amount of rows for a given date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take you want to calculate the delta of the number of records per day vs the latest available date - would the following achieve what you need:

```
import pandas as pd
# Set up the test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"Address":["2021-12-02", "2021-12-03","2021-12-03","2021-12-04", "2021-12-04", "2021-12-04"]})
df["Address"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Address"])

df2 = df.groupby("Address")[["Address"]].count().rename(columns={"Address": "count"})
# This will make sure it will calculate vs last available date
df2.at[max(df2.index),"count"] - df2
```

**OUTPUT**

```
            count
Address
2021-12-02      2
2021-12-03      1
2021-12-04      0
```

Comment: Thanks! Does this work if addresses are differernt for each line? See edit in the original post.

Comment: @LuizScheuer yes I mean in that case, if I understand your problem correctly, you are going to get a count of 1 for every address/date, hence the differential will be 0

Comment: Gotcha, yeah, you understood my request exactly. Unfortunately, there are 2 htings: 1) I am getting the following error: `KeyError: '2021-12-04'`even though that value appears in the column, and 2) does this automatically calculate the difference between the most recent date or only, specifically, '2021-12-04' and the other dates? Because I will run this code once a day and the most recent date will change.

Comment: @LuizScheuer please look at edited version. I have included the code I have used to generate the test dataset + `max(df2.index)` will make sure you can generate you report dynamically (vs last available date)

Comment: I'm checking because I am getting a number I am not supposed to get, so I'm checking if my data is flawed.